# Passing nullable custom classes as paramaters

Tags: c#, nullable

I was under the impression that if I pass a class to a function as a reference, that reference can be nullable.

Example: I have a code-first entity class / database table:

```
public class Table1
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int FillID { get; set; }
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public int FillQuantity { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDateTime { get; set; }
    public virtual tblInstruments tblInstruments { get; set; }
 }
```

I'd like to create a function which has the following signature:

```
public static void Function1 (int? i, Table1? t)
```

The `Table1? t` gives the a error:

> only non-nullable value type could be underlying of System.Nullable

So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
I tried

```
public static void Function1 (int? i, ref Table1? t)
```

But that did not resolve the issue.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: All reference variabls are by default nullable. They can take a null value. It is primitive and structs wich are not nullable by default.

Comment: Here's an article by Jon Skeet discussing value types, reference types, and passing by value or reference.  https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/references.html  After reading that take a look at the code for [`Nullable<T>`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs) which is what the `T?` is short for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All reference types are nullable by default, you don't need to add the `?` modifier. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/):

> The underlying type T can be any non-nullable value type. T cannot be a reference type.

So your code should be:

```
public static void Function1 (int? i, Table1 t)
```

The next version of C#, version 8 will introduce [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/nullable-reference-types), you will need to enable to option on a per-project basis, but that will allow you to have non-nullable reference types.

Comment: Slapping my forehead.  Duh.   Now I feel stupid :).  THANK YOU.